Asus tuf dram and cpu light and boot loop
I have a asus tuf mobo and trying to install Ubuntu when I get to the screen where it ask “try or install Ubuntu” Ubuntu graphics or memory test if I let it sit more then 30 seconds or click any option besides memory test it boot loops and the dram light pops up then the cpu light pops up and puts me back at the same screen
